# Salesforce soap error: not a valid value for the enum 'ExecutionLogType'

Tags: web-services, soap, enums, salesforce, soapui

Can anyone help me with this? I can't find information anywhere about this error message.

I created a webservice class and i'm using SoapUI just to check if it's working and I keep getting the error below.

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>'' is not a valid value for the enum 'ExecutionLogType'</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My input is below. I I don't know how to use the field Client or why it's generated in the wsdl, this field is not in my class.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:exec="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/ExecutiveCareWebservice">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <exec:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
         <exec:allowFieldTruncation>FALSE</exec:allowFieldTruncation>
      </exec:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
      <exec:DebuggingHeader>

         <exec:categories>
            <exec:category>ALL</exec:category>
            <exec:level>DEBUG</exec:level>
         </exec:categories>
         <exec:debugLevel></exec:debugLevel>
      </exec:DebuggingHeader>
      <exec:CallOptions>
         <exec:client>1</exec:client>
      </exec:CallOptions>
      <exec:SessionHeader>
         <exec:sessionId>00D0E0000008dby!ASAAQBqFFnoPgI88ekHhKy4.N0aKNAw5sIR_1LSGSqzZ_cOg.4oH9hpyW1cB2JDC._BnMKu54FhiJ4p_ORUyIQf39MbRZoqs</exec:sessionId>
      </exec:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <exec:getActiveClientes>
         <exec:validationDate></exec:validationDate>
      </exec:getActiveClientes>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance!
Joana

Comment: You lack a value in the field ExecutionLogType

Comment: Please validate your request in soapui by right click and validate. Or check xml schema for valid values.

Comment: Hi Rao, thanks for your comment. Validation is ok. I don't have that field in the wsdl. The wsdl is generated automatically by Salesforce. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your `soapenv:Header` headers. I suspect the problem is with the `exec:DebuggingHeader` header. In particular, the `exec:debugLevel` is likely related to the ExecutionLogType.

Just leave that header out completely. In fact, the only header you should need is `exec:SessionHeader`